# Is It Possible to the Take the Mode of a Tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to construct a DAG in Tensorflow where I need to take the mode (most frequent value) of individual regions of my target. This is in order to construct a downsampled target.

Right now, I'm pre-processing the downsampled targets for every individual situation I might encounter, saving them, and then loading them. Obviously, this would all be much easier if it was integrated into my Tensorflow graph, so that I could downsample at runtime.

But I've looked everywhere, and I can find no evidence of a `tf.reduce_mode`, that would function the same as [`tf.reduce_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_mean). *Is there any way to construct this functionality in a Tensorflow graph?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is that we get the unique numbers and their counts. We then find the numbers that appear most frequently. Finally we fetch those numbers (could be more than one) out by using their indices in the number-count tensor.

```py
samples = tf.constant([10, 32, 10, 5, 7, 9, 9, 9])
unique, _, count = tf.unique_with_counts(samples)
max_occurrences = tf.reduce_max(count)
max_cond = tf.equal(count, max_occurrences)
max_numbers = tf.squeeze(tf.gather(unique, tf.where(max_cond)))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print 'Most frequent Numbers\n', sess.run(max_numbers)
> Most frequent Numbers
  9
```